# Windows batch script: selecting an item from a search result list

Tags: command-line, batch-file

Objective: I'd like to search for a specific type of files in a single folder. Filtered by a specific file name pattern (e.g. "file") and also sorted by file name, the result would look like this:

```
file101.txt
file212.txt
file432.txt
```

Now, I'd like to only select the last item (here: `file432.txt`) and perform further operations (e.g. copy and rename) on that file.

How would I do that?

What I've got so far is the following:

```
@echo off
setlocal
set list=
for /r . %%g in (file*.txt) do echo %%g
```

.. which gives me the list presented at the top of my question.

As far as I understand it, there is no real list - it's just a string with return/newline characters. Consequently, I cannot really select a specific search result item. I would have used another `for` loop but I don't know exactly for which pattern I would filter except for EOF. The only idea I've got is to remove all newline characters and save the result in a variable. Now every new line that is found would overwrite the previous one.

How would I do this?

```
set lastitem=for %%g in (%list%) do REMOVE_NEWLINE and echo %%g
```

Comment: Another question, [similar solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30311479/3439404) if you do modify `/O` switch of `dir` command. Read `dir /?` for possible sort order values.

Comment: Jim, I hope you realize that the `/R` option is used to go into sub-folders.  So the answer you accepted will not work if it needs to do that as files are sorted per each folder it is accessing during execution. Everything is output alphanumerically per the folder and file name.  This code also only works if all the files have the same file name structure. If any of your file names have more or less numeric characters you will may or may not get the file name that is the largest numeric number.

Comment: @Squashman, I wasn't aware of that detail, however it did work (hence accepting the answer) as expected due the very specific limitations which were indeed described by you. Feel free to alter the question accordingly to address this matter better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### I'd like to only select the last item

> (here: file432.txt) and perform further operations (e.g. copy and rename) on that file.

Use the following batch file.

**test.cmd:**

```
@echo off 
setlocal
for /r . %%g in (file*.txt) do (
  set _lastitem=%%g
  )
echo do something to the last file in the list, which is %_lastitem%
endlocal
```

**example output:**

```
F:\test>dir file*.txt
 Volume in drive F is Expansion
 Volume Serial Number is 3656-BB63

 Directory of F:\test

22/08/2016  18:17                 0 file101.txt
22/08/2016  18:17                 0 file212.txt
22/08/2016  18:17                 0 file432.txt
               3 File(s)              0 bytes
               0 Dir(s)  1,765,302,566,912 bytes free

F:\test>test
do something to the last file in the list, which is F:\test\file432.txt

F:\test>
```

Comment: Worked like a charm. The only minor thing I would improve is to use quotation marks: "%_lastitem%". This way directory paths with spaces won't give troubles. :D